# FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app)., js engine: hermes

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I was working with the original web `firebase SDK` but since I found out I want/need to use [notifee](https://notifee.app/react-native/docs/integrations/fcm) I want to switch to [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/). my project is set up with expo but I needed to use some additional packages so I did a build, thus my expo workflow is now bare. Therefore following the official [react-native-firebase-expo-installation](https://rnfirebase.io/#expo-bare-workflow) docs I installed the `rnf/app` and downloaded the firebase google-keys (info.plist and services for both OS systems). Although after many tries and struggles I was not successful and I still get an error: `FirebaseError: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call initializeApp() first (app/no-app)., js engine: hermes`

I also tried the `Expo Managed Workflow` docs but neither of the solutions did not work for me.

Any suggestions please? Thanks!